# Splitting string based on a list in R

Tags: r, string

Suppose I have a list like:

```
l= c(“ab”,”abc”, “kit”, “Loki”, “kits”, “a”)
```

Then I have a string:

```
string = “0abcab73kit(kits67)loki2”
```

My end goal is to get an output that shows if the string contains the list elements, so a possible output is:

```
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE
```

I think a combination of `strsplit` and `grepl(..., fixed=T)` may work, but there’re few points to note:

1. Take the longer string if possible, so for example, “0abc...”, we will take “abc” rather than “ab” because “abc” is also exists in the list and is longer.
2. Upper’Lower case letters treat the same, so “Loki” is equal to “loki”

Comment: If you have "abca" in your `l` what would be your output for "ab", "abc", "abca" and "a" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to detect if `string` contains the elements in list `l`, in order of numbers of characters and also removing those elements that have been previously found.

If this is the case then do:

```
library(stringr)
l= c("ab","abc", "kit", "Loki", "kits", "a")
string = "0abcab73kit(kits67)loki2"

# Reorder your list by number of characters (longest first)
l = l[order(nchar(l), decreasing = T)]

# Then use `sapply` and remove the found elements from `string`
out = sapply(l, function(x){
  if( str_detect(string, regex(x, ignore_case = T)) ){
    string <<- str_remove(string, regex(x, ignore_case = T))
    return(TRUE)
  }
  return(FALSE)
})
```

This gives:

```
> out
 Loki  kits   abc   kit    ab     a 
 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Warning:

The original string is modified in the process. If you want to keep it, make a copy and modify the copy. This is due to the `string <<-`.

Comment: But “a” should be FALSE in this example, unless my string is like “0a0”, then “a” exist.

Comment: That’s true, but I only want the longest string; for example, if my string is ‘ 01abc9’, indeed it contains ‘a’, ‘ab’ and ‘abc’, but only ‘abc’ will count because it is the longer string.

Comment: Deleted my comments because the answer was completely modified.